# Image gets randomly half corrupted

Tags: wordpress, image

[image]

This image will randomly become corrupted, like above, when gathered through [Simply Static](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/simply-static/) (also reproduced with NGINX Caching server).

Then if I were to visit the actual page displaying this image on WordPress, it's corrupted as well! Except if I do a HARD Refresh (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>), then it comes back to normal.

I just have no idea how that could happen, hence my question in here!

[Running through docker wordpress:5.0.3]

Well, actually, even without any Caching mechanism the issue can still happens.

Comment: If this is live site then share URL for the better understanding

Comment: This isn't a live Website, it looks as if Wordpress/Apache fails to transport the image and then it's like that. But then trying another time fixes the issue, (basically CTRL + F5). Available to answer any question.

Comment: Try with delete your whole browser cache. And as per my knowledge hard refresh is (CTRL + SHIFT + R) not (CTRL + F5).
One more solution check in private window for  FIREFOX(CTRL + SHIFT + P) AND for chome (CTRL + SHIFT + N)

Comment: Upon using CTRL + F5, the image is refreshed and won't be half corrupted anymore. My issue is that it happens in the 1st place.

Comment: I have automation grabbing those images, and if when grabbed the image is half corrupted, this is what's going to end up in prod.

Comment: Looks like increasing the memory_limit from 128MB to 256MB fixed, still double checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing PHP memory_limit property did the trick.
I also optimized those images.